# Pass callback function with argument as parameter to other function

Tags: c++, callback, argument-passing

I have this:

```
// Call back function take string argument by ref.
typedef void (*Callback)(string&);
```

And I have this too:

```
// Function that take Callback as an argument
void need_a_callback (Callback func) {

    // Do something

}
```

The function that will be called back:

```
void modify(string& text) {

    text = "";

}
```

And now, how can I pass `modify` to `need_a_callback`?

Comment: What happened when you tried `need_a_callback(modify);`?

Comment: If I do that, where is the argument for `modify`?

Comment: @BagolDaplun, You pass it when you call the callback.

Comment: You seem to want to couple passing in a callback and passing in its arguments, but there's not necessarily a reason to do such coupling. If you _need_ it in your application, your `need_a_callback()` function needs another argument, such as `void need_a_callback(Callback func, String& argument)`.

Comment: @mah You get my point. That's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks are function pointers. So you pass callbacks like pointers.

It results in this :

```
need_a_callback(modify);
```

Then, in need_a_callback(), you call your callback like this :

```
// Function that take Callback as an argument
void need_a_callback (Callback func) {

    String text = "my text";
    func(text);

}
```